Double agent wearing a wire gets caught in a car
In a car, some man in a suit gets his cover blown because 1 or 2 other people tear off his shirt and expose that the man is wearing a microphone attached with scotchtape to his chest under a white shirt. So the man was a cop or a doubleagent infiltrating  the other gang or something but I can't remember more. I'm fairly certain that it's 15-20 years old. I think it was a TV movie in the 1980s.
I believe it was a US TV movie or TV series that also aired in Europe. Unfortunately I don't remember anything else but the car scene. I only remember the specific scene where the man was in a backseat of a car, wearing a suit, one or two other guys suspected that he was wearing a microphone, they ripped up his white shirt and there was white duct tape attaching wires and a microphone clearly showing that the man was recording audio. It's similar to a DePalma or Coppola scenario but I don't think it's that.

That's a very common plotline in movies, what country, language and genre was it? And is there anything else you remember about the films?

I believe it was a US TV movie or TV series that also aired in Europe. Unfortunately I don't remember anything else but the car scene. I only remember the specific scene where the man was in a backseat of a car, wearing a suit, one or two other guys suspected that he was wearing a microphone, they ripped up his white shirt and there was white duct tape attaching wires and a microphone clearly showing that the man was recording audio. It's similar to a DePalma or Coppola scenario but I don't think it's that.

If it's 15-20 years old, it's not from the 80s. Do you mean it was at least 15-20 years old?

I can believe it was produced in the 80s and that I saw it in the 90s. My guess is that it's newer than the original Miami Vice (Don Johnson etc), or it could have been an original Miami Vice episode?

Ok, I've added your comment into the question to give my answer a bit more substance.

@SonnyBurnett I'm 99,9 % certain it is the Miami Vice you say. It is the only one that it could be that I've seen. When I see it again I'll remember the camera angles and more. Might try netflix or likewise to find it.

As has been said, this is quite a common scenario in the movies. But as you mentioned Miami Vice, I'd throw that in as a possible answer.
Something like this happened in the 1984 Miami Vice episode "Heart of Darkness" (S01E02). Tubbs and Crockett are riding in a limo with the bad guys (and an Ed O'Neill with uncertain affiliation). But due to bad wiring Tubbs' microphone suddenly starts playing music and thus arises the suspicion of the gangsters, who open his shirt and remove it.
While being quite a common movie scene, it seems even more likely when considering your additional information, as the mic is typed to his chest with white duct tape. And while he doesn't exactly wear a white shirt, he wears a very light blue shirt with a white suit over it. So it may be worth a try, given that it's a TV "movie" from the 80s.
